# warbler seems to use a different ffi that doesn't understand size_t

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails, ffi, warbler

FFI understands `:size_t` when running rails through jRuby, but not after using Warbler to create a .war file and running that using `java -jar my_project.war` or Tomcat.

```
                       Linux | Windows
-----------------------------+-------------
java -jar              works | doesn't work
tomcat                 works | doesn't work
rails s (using jruby)  works | works
```

Linux and Windows use the same war file in the comparison.

Here is the top of a backtrace from running `java -jar` on Windows. (I've edited the beginnings of the file paths in the backtrace).

```
--- Backtrace
TypeError: unable to resolve type 'size_t'
  find_type at jar:file:/my_project.war/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.7.2.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/ffi/types.rb:55
  type_size at jar:file:/my_project.war/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-1.7.2.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/ffi/types.rb:147
SQLAnywhere at my_project.war/WEB-INF/gems/gems/sqlanywhere-ffi-1.0.1/lib/sqlanywhere.rb:13
     (root) at my_project.war/WEB-INF/gems/gems/sqlanywhere-ffi-1.0.1/lib/sqlanywhere.rb:5
    require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027
```

When I look at the files in the backtrace, they list various c types, but not `size_t`.

It seems to me that there are 2 FFIs available to jRuby.

- The [normal FFI gem](https://github.com/ffi/ffi).
- The jruby-stdlib ffi.

The big difference between the 2, seems to be that only the former understands `:size_t`.

My question is: Are there 2 different FFIs?
If so: how do I make sure that my gem loads the correct ffi?
If not: what am I doing wrong?

PS: I'm the author of the sqlanywhere-ffi gem, so if the problem is I'm depending on the wrong thing, I can change it. Currently it has ffi as a depenendency in the gemspec, the gemfile and it `requires 'ffi'` in the main entry point.

Answer (score 3):

> (I've edited the beginnings of the file paths in the backtrace).

I guess the full path of your Tomcat-directory contains whitespaces, make sure it doesn't.

This problem did not occur with jruby-1.6 versions.

Comment: Any fixes? Appears with jruby176

Comment: Make sure the path to your webapps-directory does not contain whitespaces, that should fix this issue. Unfortunately i had a lot of other unresolved issues with jruby 1.7.6. Dowgrading to 1.7.4 "fixed" them.